# Django Correct Usage of Models.Cascade (on_delete)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to work what is the correct usage of the models.cascade statement. I have two models Cart and Entry. If I delete an Entry the deletion is not updated on the Cart Entry. I have checked this via the admin interface. My models.py is as below:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart:{} User:{} Items:{} Total:£{}".format(self.id, self.user, self.count, self.total)

class Entry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does on\_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)

Comment: model.cascade isn't actually getting rid of the record for me. So if I delete an entry, the cart is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your concept of the cascade backwards. Based on your model, your `Entry` will be deleted when you call delete on the `Cart` for the foreign key relationship. If you wanted the deletion to work in reverse you would need to add some additional code to handle that. You could look at [Django cascade delete on reverse foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655347/django-cascade-delete-on-reverse-foreign-keys) for some ideas on how to implement that (if that is what you need).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not associating **Entry** and **Cart**,Just set the Entry ForeignKey and use on_delete. When you delete an Cart the deletion, the Entry associated with it will be deleted.